# Embed a (child) component in v-list-item

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, listitem

I have a component which open a dialog to add a new record (job). The component works fine when added to toolbar. I am now making the app responsive and when it's viewed on a tablet I have added a menu and inside the menu, I am adding this component but it doesn't show up. O have added buttons on top and bottom and they leave empty space in the middle but nothing shows up or opens when I click that empty space.

P.S.: I am new and this is my first Vue App

I have tried surrounding it within template tag, still nothing works

```
    <v-menu offset-y >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn fab text v-on="on" class="hidden-md-and-up">
          <v-icon>mdi-menu</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item>
          <v-btn to="/" exact text >    
            <v-icon class="mr-1" right>mdi-clipboard-list-outline</v-icon>
          <span>Board</span>
        </v-btn>
        </v-list-item>
        <v-list-item>
          <template>
          <AddNewJob @jobAdded="snackbar = true" />
          </template>
        </v-list-item>
        <v-list-item>
          <v-btn to="about" exact text >    
            <v-icon class="mr-1">mdi-information-outline</v-icon>
            <span>About</span>
          </v-btn>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>

The component in question is AddNewJob
```

Comment: can you create a codepen for the same issue, it would really help to resolve your issue easier..

Comment: Solved. I used dark in Child Component button and then no background in Menu hence did not see it. Novice mistake.